# Using custom "merge fields" in email resource files

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to use custom “Merge Fields” in the email resource file?

According to https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-email-resource-file-v1-1  it is possilbe to use merge fields for DocuSign data e.g. [Data:RecipientName]]

Additionally we want to use merge fields for non DocuSign data.

For example a hotline number that is based on customers (signers) segment). The hotline number is part of the rest-api-call as a recipient custom field

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a way to leverage custom merge fields in this manner, even if the metadata is stored as recipient custom field data.