# DocuSign custom merge field in email resource file

Tags: docusignapi

[Email resource file](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/docusign-email-resource-file(v1.1).pdf)

Is it possible to use custom merge fields in the email resource file?

I did setting custom field in envelope definition when creating an envelope.

```
$tc = new TextCustomField();
$tc->setName('PreparedBy');
$tc->setValue(Auth::user()->name);

$customFields = new CustomFields();
$customFields->setTextCustomFields([$tc]);

$envelopDefinition->setCustomFields($customFields);
```

Then referred as `[[Conditional:PreparedBy]]Document Prepared By : [[Data:PreparedBy]]` in email resource file, but didn't work.

Any help ?

**Note:** There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103562/using-custom-merge-fields-in-email-resource-files) posted long time back and not answered. Posting a new to draw attention.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct:

> Unfortunately there is not a way to leverage custom merge fields in
>   this manner, even if the metadata is stored as recipient custom field
>   data.

This is true of both Recipient Custom Fields and of Envelope Custom Fields.

If you need to define a custom email message, the EmailBlurb parameter can be used in the envelope creation call.